# Facet groups in Solr - is this possible in one query

Tags: solr, facet, faceted-search

I'm working with facets in Solr and I have the concept of facet groups that each contain a number of facets.

Say I have a structure like this

```
Product Type
- Chairs (50)
- Tables (20)
- Mirrors (5)

Color
- Yellow (5)
- Black (50)
- Red (10)
- Orange (10)
```

I have an OR relationship between facets within a facet group and an AND relationship between the groups.

So if I choose `Chairs` as a facet I get 50 products. Using the standard faceting in Solr (and assuming that each product can have exactly one product type and one color) it will now give:

```
Product Type
- Chairs (50)
- Tables (0)
- Mirrors (0)

Color
- Yellow (5)
- Black (30)
- Red (5)
- Orange (10)
```

However, what I really want is that **the facet counts within Product Type stay the same** as that would reflect what would happen if one of them was chosen.

Can this be done with Solr in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can implemented [using tagged filters and then excluding them](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Tagging_and_excluding_Filters) when creating the facet.

From the referenced page:

> To implement a multi-select facet for doctype, a GUI may want to still display the other doctype values and their associated counts, as if the doctype:pdf constraint had not yet been applied. Example:

```
=== Document Type ===
  [ ] Word (42)
  [x] PDF  (96)
  [ ] Excel(11)
  [ ] HTML (63)
```

> To return counts for doctype values that are currently not selected, tag filters that directly constrain doctype, and exclude those filters when faceting on doctype.

```
q=mainquery&fq=status:public&fq={!tag=dt}doctype:pdf&facet=on&facet.field={!ex=dt}doctype
```

> Filter exclusion is supported for all types of facets. Both the tag and ex local params may specify multiple values by separating them with commas.